# r fit logistic curve through three points

Tags: r, plot, curve-fitting

I have three points (1,4) (3,6) (2,5),the (2,5)is the midpoints .how to  fit  a particular kind of logistic curves like the following figure.
[image]

Comment: A [logistic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) (generally) has 3 parameters, which means the curve is uniquely defined by 3 points. In other words, there are infinite many logistic curves that pass through two points. So your system is underdetermined.

Comment: What is the scale of values in the x and y?

Comment: Thank you for @Maurits Evers .If I add other the point c(2,5) as the midpoint, how tohow to fit a particular kind of logistic curve?

Comment: As I said, there exists a **unique 3-par logistic curve that passes through 3 points**; you can obtain coefficients from algebraically solving 3 equations for 3 coefficients.

Comment: Now that the question has been edited to have three data points, I found that a dose-response curve similar in shape to a logistic seems to fit the new data fairly well. Please try "y = b + (a-b) / (1.0 + pow(10.0, c - x))" with parameters a = 6.065, b = 3.935 and c = 2.0 and see if it might meet your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I fit a modified logistic with two parameters, "y = a / (1.0 + b*exp(-X))" with parameters a =  6.5094194977264266E+00 and b =  1.7053273551626427E+00 - see attached graph. I recommend not using this as it is a perfect fit with no errors, two parameters and two data points.

[image: model.png]

Comment: This is incorrect. A fit of a general 3-parameter logistic curve through 2 points is **not** a *"perfect with without errors"*. It's an underdetermined system, as there are infinite many possibilities to draw a logistic curve through 2 points. There exists a unique solution only for 3 points, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512468/logistic-curve-through-three-points).

Comment: If you would please, kindly re-read my answer for the purpose of counting the number of parameters.

Comment: You can see from OPs drawing that the expected curve's midpoint is somewhere within the interval `[1, 3]`; so simply assuming a 2 parameter logistic curve with zero midpoint is not correct.